# Java float / double subtract

Tags: java

I want to make simple subtract operation on float so that I don't get a final decimal but I got same result with float

Better than my bad english : code !

```
    private double test(final double reloadingTime) {
    double timeRestant = reloadingTime - 0.1;
    System.out.println(timeRestant);
    return timeRestant;
}
```

main :

```
    double test = test(2f);
    test = test(test);
    test = test(test);
    test = test(test);
    test = test(test);
    test = test(test);
```

console :

```
1.9
1.7999999999999998
1.6999999999999997
1.5999999999999996
1.4999999999999996
1.3999999999999995
```

So two questions: Why?
And how can I can get the true result?

Comment: Fundamentally, if you want to use exact *decimal* values, use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Also make sure to use BigDecimal(String) constructor.